# Bash script to extract audio from video

Tags: bash, audio, video, libav

I have written this little script to batch extract audio from video using avconv. It was working fine, but strangely it doesn't work anymore (since I have changed the codec from aac to mp3).

The script is supposed to test each file in a folder. If it is a video, it should extract the audio from it.

Can somebody help me fix this?

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Batch conversion of audio extraction from video
# doesnt work with mkv files (file -i *.mkv returns application/octet)

FOLDER_SRC="/home/J/Music/TestBatchConv"

for myvid in $(find ${FOLDER_SRC})
do
    if file -i $myvid | grep -q video ;
        then avconv -i $myvid -acodec libmp3lame "${myvid}.mp3"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: What is it not doing? Is it not detecting video? Is avconv not working? Any error messages?

Comment: cursor blinking but no conversion nor error message... ´file -i *.* | grep video´ returns the video (mp4/video charshet=binary) but nothing happens... now i have changed the script with grep | mp4 but same : cursor blinking and no errors...

Comment: Crossposted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486270/bash-script-to-batch-extract-audio-from-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're using an old version of `file` where [MKV files weren't detected properly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file/+bug/420963). You can use [this `~/.magic` file](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/61531679/.magic) to have `file` identify MKV.

But actually, the most reliable way to check for valid video files would be to just run `avconv` and see if it fails or not. Here's what you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER_SRC="/home/J/Music/TestBatchConv"
find "$FOLDER_SRC" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' myvid; do
  echo "Trying to convert $myvid"
  avconv -i "$myvid" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "${myvid%.*}.mp3" 2>/dev/null || echo "$myvid is not a valid file."
done
```

If the file is not valid video, or there's any error, `avconv` will exit anyway.

Some tips and explanation:

- There's [no need to parse the output of `ls` or `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Simply do `for myvid in "$FOLDER_SRC"/*`, or for a recursive version, use the `**` glob with the `globstar` option. Here, the `find … | while …` line can be replaced with:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  for myvid in "$FOLDER_SRC/**"; do
  ```
- Don't forget to properly quote `"$myvid"` wherever you use it in the loop, otherwise videos with whitespace in their name break your script.
- You can remove the original file extension by removing anything after the last dot `${myvid%.*}` and replace it with `.mp3`.
- You should tell `avconv` to use [variable bitrate encoding](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio) for `libmp3lame`, e.g. with `-q:a 4`, with values ranging from 0–10, and 4 being the default. This will give you better audio quality in general.

Comment: thank you again, but sry all i got is `4.2.25(1)-release and  
/home/J/Music/TestBatchConv/ is not a valid file.` like if the files test even don't happen. yes I am a noob at this ^^

Comment: It seems the loop is picking up your conversion folder. If you use the right glob, e.g. `"$FOLDER_SRC"/**`, this won't include the folder itself though. If you use the `**` glob you just need to check if every item found is actually a file. Make sure it's using the right path (maybe add a `echo "$myvid"` in the loop to check). If you're not using the script I gave you, please show what exactly your script now looks like.

Comment: I changed it exactly how you suggested (without the find) and it works. there is 2 issues not resolved : 1) the folder itself is tested (even with the `"$FOLDER_SRC"/**`) and 2) i don't have the avconv message anymore (and that point was mistaken me)

Comment: and VBR is not suitable as I want to use my songs on a 2nd generation ipod (and i have a problem when encoding in VBR with libav as far as i cant navigate in the song on the ipod)

Comment: Ah, yeah. I thought of suppressing the `avconv` output with `2>/dev/null`. Leave out that part if you want all the info.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested here is the final working code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Batch conversion of audio extraction from video

echo $BASH_VERSION
FOLDER_SRC="/home/J/Music/TestBatchConv"

shopt -s globstar

for myvid in "$FOLDER_SRC"/**
do
  echo "$myvid"
  avconv -i "$myvid" -acodec libmp3lame "${myvid%.*}.mp3" 2>/dev/null || echo "$myvid is not a valid file."
done
exit 0
```